Understanding these definitions for ～ではないか
I was looking up the definitions for ～ではないか and ～のではないか in Sanseidou and I encountered three similar-looking definitions:

ではないか｟終助｠
①問いかけや推量をあらわす。〔ほぼ断定している場合もある〕
「うそ━・問題があるの━」


のではないか｟終助｠〔←助動詞「のだ」の連用形「ので」＋副助詞「は」＋形容詞「ない」＋終助詞「か」〕
①根拠(こんきょ)にもとづいた問いかけや推量をあらわす。
「君、それはちがう━？〔＝ちがうだろう。ちがうよ〕・景気は上向いていく━」
②根拠もなく考えることをあらわす。
「ほっとけば、だれかがやってくれる━・〔おそれて〕敵が攻(せ)めてくる━」

I have three questions related to these definitions. I think they are related to each other and I hope I am not asking too much. I can open a separate post if needed.

I don't completely understand the definition ① of ～ではないか. So this ～ではないか is used for asking questions or make conjecture, and there are cases when it is used to state assert something is true? The example sentence うそではないか？⤴ (note rising intonation) means "Isn't it a lie?" or "It is probably a lie?" And I am not sure what is meant by ほぼ断定している場合もある. Also, unlike the other ～ではないか used for expressing surprise or anger, when a sentence ends with a verb, one must first normalize it with の before ending it with ではないか, as in example sentence 問題があるのではないか?

It seems like the definition ① of ～のではないか is the same as the definition ① of ～ではないか but the explanatory の is involved, right? Now the problem is that the sentence 問題があるのではないか is ambiguous. の in this sentence can either be explanatory or normalizing. Maybe the context will tell?

I also don't understand the definition ② of ～のではないか. I would like some example sentences with translations demonstrating this usage. It looks like の no longer functions as an explanatory の, unlike the previous definition. I am not sure how to explain this kind of の but I think it acts as a "softener." So, when asserting that A is true, instead of using Aではないか, which sounds strong, one can use Aのではないか to be gentle.



ほぼ断定している場合もある means, in response to じゃない[か] being used as inquiry and/or conjecture, that it is also used when the speaker is mostly sure of their assertion, rendering it mostly rhetorical if posed as a question.

Does it help you if I say English has a somewhat similar construction with "isn't it so?", as in "The modern world has gotten more and more digitalized, isn't it/is it not so?" You're not actually asking a question.

Hmm, now that I think about it, I am unsure about the difference between isn't it and is it not so?


ではない・じゃない　is used to state what something is not. The addition of the particle か acts as an expression of doubt, turning a hard statement into something more of a hunch.
This does not necessarily turn the phrase into a question. That depends on the tone employed. In the same way that the way you say "huh?" can be in disbelief or derision, か can do the same. 「うそではないか」would likely be translated as "That's a lie," but weaken how sure you are about it. 「うそではないか？」said with a rising tone would be a stronger lack of certainty; "That's a lie, isn't it?"

The use of a nominalizing の in the example sentence is not indicative of whether the sentence ends in a verb or not, its a function of the particle で and the verb だ which derives from it -- all particles describe how a noun or phrase connects to a verb, since だ is both the particle で and the verb ある, it attaches to nouns like a particle, but also acts like the verb that the particle connects it to. So, full sentences (phrases that end in verbs) must be nominalized to attach だ. This is true in any scenario (except for i-adjectives where です is used for marking politeness), not just this particular phrase.

You are correct to think that this is both. The structure of のだ literally translates to "To be (that which) is of...", vaguely similar to the concept in English of ending an explanation with "X, Y, and Z is the thing." The Nominalization and Explanatory uses of の are derived from this structure.

Specifically, the Nominalization usage is based on the fact that の is used to attach a phrase to a noun to mark possession. For example, 「ヘンリーの本」literally means "The book that is of Henry". If we remove the modified noun, we get 「ヘンリーの」"To be of Henry". The concept of "thing" is implied by this structure, which creates the nominal usage. 「歌うの」means "(Things) that are of singing" = "Singing as a thing". Furthermore, the Explanatory usage is specific to のだ because its an extension of the Nominalization usage with the stative verb だ, as shown in the translation I've described in the above paragraph.
As a general rule, the usages of particles should not be considered hard distinctions, but as different functions of the same terms.

This is simply the nominal usage of の. These entries do not indicate different meanings of のではないか, they're just different specificities of the same idea. In the first definition, it uses のではないか to assert something evidential, that can be verified, "The economy is going up, huh?"; and in the second definition, its when you don't have evidence or are basing it off of a gut-feeling, "The enemy is going to attack us, aren't they!"

Hope that helps!
